# .NET querying Aspnetusers instead of Custom AuthUser and Yet AspNetUser does not Exist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dot

I write a custom IdentityUser which is AuthUser.

```
public class AuthUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public int StudentsId { get; set; }
        public virtual Students StudentProfile { get; set; }

        public int InstructorId { get; set; }
        public virtual Instructor InstructorProfile { get; set; }

        public bool IsStudent { get; set; }
        public bool IsInstructor { get; set; }
    }
```

The context is okay as you can see

```
 public class LmsContext : IdentityDbContext<AuthUser> //DbContext
    {
}
```

The startup.cs is all setup

```
services.AddDbContext<LmsContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("UCIPrimarySchool"))
                );
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<AuthUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<LmsContext>();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
```

But when I try to login I get the following error.

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__169_0(Task<SqlDataReader> result)
```

Why is is not querying the extended AuthUser but instead goes for the none existing table AspNetUsers?

Comment: have you created migrations and updated the database?

Comment: What is the relationship between your `AuthUser`, `Student and Instructor`? Can you share your `Student` and `Instructor` classes?

Comment: Yes I updated the Database, The Student and Instructor as just profile unique to each of those two candidates

Comment: Hi @wangolo joel， can you share the `Student and Instructor` model with us?

Comment: Is the relationship between them one to one?

Comment: Yes it's one to one

Comment: Hi@wangolo joel,you can see my update answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should clarify your relationship and then migrations and updated the database correctly.

Change your AuthUser like this:

```
public class AuthUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual Students StudentProfile { get; set; }

    public virtual Instructor InstructorProfile { get; set; }

    public bool IsStudent { get; set; }
    public bool IsInstructor { get; set; }
}
```

In your `Context`:

```
  public DbSet<Students>  Students { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Instructor> Instructor { get; set; }
```

Migration and update:
[image]

After successfully updating the database, you need to change your `View/Shared/_LoginPartial` code:

```
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
```

to

```
@inject SignInManager<AuthUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<AuthUser> UserManager
```

Then
[image]
[image]

`Select your LmsContext`   Add
[image]

Then start your app,and login.

Comment: Interesting details thanks, I got the crucial parts working.